# in R, predict yields wrong length

Tags: r, predict

`new.y = predict(model, newx = new.x)`,
the length of new.y is different from the row length of new.x

Code is here:

```
install.packages('ISLR')
library(ISLR)

fix(Hitters)   # load data
Hitters = na.omit(Hitters)   # remove NA

x = model.matrix(Salary ~ ., Hitters)[ , -1]
y = Hitters$Salary

set.seed(1)
train = sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)/2)   # random sampling
test = (-train)

lm.fit = lm(y ~ x, subset=train)  
lm.pred = predict( lm.fit, newx = x[test,])

dim(x[test,])   # output 132*19
length(lm.pred)   # output 131
length(y[test])   # output 132
```

Does anybody know why the length is wrong? Thanks!

Update: the mistake is `newx = x[test, ]` wasn't recognized by `predict`
Thanks @Pascal!
To make it more obvious:

```
install.packages('ISLR')
library(ISLR)

fix(Hitters)   # load data
Hitters = na.omit(Hitters)   # remove NA

x = model.matrix(Salary ~ ., Hitters)[ , -1]
y = Hitters$Salary

set.seed(2)
train = sample(1:nrow(x), 150)   # random sampling (specify size for testing)
test = (1:nrow(x))[-train]


lm.fit = lm(y ~ x, subset=train)
lm.pred = predict( lm.fit, newx = x[test,])
dim(x[test,])   # output 113  19
length(lm.pred)   # output 150 - still using training data


lm.fit = lm(Salary ~ ., data = Hitters, subset = train)
lm.pred = predict( lm.fit, newdata = Hitters[test,])
dim(x[test,])   # output 113  19
length(lm.pred)   # output 113
```

The ways of defining `test` in the 1st and 2nd code should work the same. Test:

```
x = c('A','B','C','D','E')
set.seed(2)
n = length(x)
train = sample(1:n, n/2)   # random sampling
test = -train
test   # output -1 -3
x[test]   # output "B" "D" "E"

test = (1:n)[-train]
test   # output 2 4 5
x[test]   # output "B" "D" "E"
```

Comment: `newx` is not a valid option for `predict.lm`. `x[test,]` is not used.

Comment: Also, did you check the values of `test`?

Comment: Hi @Pascal, thanks a lot! `newx` wasn't used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify with:

```
library(ISLR)

Hitters <- na.omit(Hitters)   # remove NA

set.seed(1)
train <- sample(1:nrow(Hitters), nrow(Hitters)/2)   # random sampling
test <- (1:nrow(Hitters))[-train]  # your definition of test was incorrect

lm.fit <- lm(Salary ~ ., data = Hitters, subset = train)  
lm.pred <- predict(lm.fit, newdata = Hitters[test,])

dim(Hitters[test,])   # output 132*20
length(lm.pred)   # output 132
```

Comment: Is `test` needed - maybe just use `newdata = Hitters[-train, ]` in the `predict`, but not important

Comment: Yes, right. I wanted to highlight the mistake of the OP, but your remark is a more straightforward way.

Comment: Hi @Pascal, I tried something and I think maybe both way work the same, see this: `x = c('A','B','C','D','E')
set.seed(2)
n = nrow(x)
train = sample(1:n, n/2)   # random sampling
test = -train
test
x[test]

test = (1:length(x))[-train]
test
x[test]`    Thanks for your help~

Comment: Hi @Pascal, i don't know how to change line in the comment, so the code looks ugly. I'll update in the OP. Please help with continue discussion~ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try providing a data.frame to the argument `newdata` as in:

```
lm.pred <- predict(lm.fit,
                   newdata=data.frame(x=x[test,],y=0))
```

Also, I'm not sure the argument `subset` is doing what you think it is doing. I would instead provide the argument `data` in your call to `lm` as in:

```
lm.fit = lm(y ~ x, 
            data=data.frame(x=x,y=y)[train,])
```

Comment: `y` is not required here.

Comment: @Pascal really?  when I remove it from the data.frame in the call to predict, it reverts to the original data used to fit the model.

Comment: I get the same results.

Comment: Oops, your right, I had x, and y reversed in my R session.  Edited response accordinlgy.

Comment: Thank you guys~ I tried a few things and none of them work... See the picture please. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EHYRPZSyc8VlpWeUU3YkgzUTQ/view?usp=sharing) Any idea why it's not working? Thank you! The complete code is here (see line 15) [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EHYRPZSyc8b2tNc01iVXdSM2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The code above was just a toy example to show that each of the predictors need to be in the data.frame passed to the argument `newdata`.  (in the toy example the only predictor was `x`).   In your case, you need to pass `Hitters[train,]` since you specified all fields in the data.frame in your forumla `Salary ~ .`  (since `.` means all the remaining variables in the dataset...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
install.packages('ISLR')
library(ISLR)

fix(Hitters)   # load data
Hitters = na.omit(Hitters)   # remove NA

x = Hitters[,-1] 
y = Hitters$Salary

set.seed(1)
train = sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)/2)   # random sampling
test_data <- x[-train,]
y_test <- y[-train]
y_train<-y[train]
train_data <- data.frame(Y= y[train],x[train,]) 

lm.fit = lm(Y ~ ., train_data)  
lm.pred = predict( lm.fit, newx = test_data)

dim(test_data)   # output 161*19
length(lm.pred)   # output 130
length(y_test)   # output 161
```

I guess the difference in length of lm.pred is due to the null values in y